# Using mod to wrap around

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume the array has a length of 1000. I am trying to create a simple way to traverse the image paths stored in the array without going out of bounds. The method below handles the wrap around using modulus well when it comes to clicking the 'next' button to increment array index, but not when I have to decrement and deduct one from the index  (when the user clicks the previous button).

Basically what I am trying to do is:

```
998 -> click next -> 999
999 -> click next -> 0
0 -> click previous -> 999
```

My Javacript

```
var index = 0;

$('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[index]);
$(".next").click(function(){
        $('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[++index%arrayLength]);
    });         
$(".previous").click(function(){
    $('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[--index]);
    alert(index);
```

I appreciate any help with

Many thank in advance.

Comment: `--index%arrayLength` should work just fine.

Comment: tried that, it does not work.

Comment: @Shmiddty Should, but doesn't.

Comment: Oh, I see, the problem is when index is less than 0.

Comment: Have you tried an if/else statement?

Comment: Too bad that I came late to the party. Still posted an answer for the record

Comment: The formula is: `(index+arrayLength) % arrayLength`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There might be a more elegant way around this, but this is simple:

```
$(".previous").click(function(){
    if (--index < 0) index = arrayLength - 1;
    $('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[index%arrayLength]);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the length of the array prior to taking the modulo:

```
index = (index + arrayLength) % arrayLength
```

Comment: same problem when index is less than `-arrayLength`

Comment: Fixed. Looks like a two-step problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One of your solutions before the edits worked for me. However, this does not work.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a handy object for it.

```
var Cursor = function (array) {
  var idx = 0;
  this.prev = function () {
    idx = (!!idx ? idx : array.length) - 1;
    return array[idx];
  };
  this.current = function () {
    return array[idx];
  };
  this.next = function () {
    idx = (idx + 1) % array.length;
    return array[idx];
  };
  return this;
};
```

For example,

```
var $container = $(".catalog-img-container");
var cursor = new Cursor(javascript_array);

$container.attr("src", cursor.current());

$(".next").click(function(){
  $container.attr("src", cursor.next());
});         

$(".previous").click(function(){
  $container.attr("src", cursor.prev());
});
```

Comment: +1 for handy object. I'd probably write it differently myself, but the concept is good. :)

Comment: @Shmiddty, don't know how that helps but ok. Nice touch

Answer (score 0):

Umm, not sure if this is what you wanted but:

```
$(".previous").click(function(){if (index-1 <0){index = arrayLength -1;}

            $('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[--index]);
            //alert(index);
        });
```

I am assuming arrayLength = javascript_array.length;

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**[WORKING DEMO TEST](http://jsbin.com/eqenag/1/edit)**

This is all you need:

```
var index=0;

$('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[index]);

$(".next, .previous").click(function(){

  var MyClass = $(this).hasClass('next') ? index++ : index-- ;
  index = index==-1 ? arrayLength-1 : index%arrayLength ;  
  $('.catalog-img-container').attr("src", javascript_array[index]);

});
```

Comment: `index == index-1` will never be true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This seems like a complex solution :)

Comment: @roXon You edited your answer, why are you bothering to compare the edit to my first comment (your original answer)? The whole point of the comment was to point out a mistake (likely a brainfart, right?) No need to be difficult about it. :)

Comment: @Shmiddty I don't remember my very first edit, I just know I had one where I added a demo, but could be I was working around my answer. Thanks any way! :) hahha brainfart :) you made my day!

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* @param {number} counter
* @param {number} maxValue
* @return {number}
* @desc Always returns a number between 0 and maxValue. Can be used to 
iterate through an array without "Range out of bounds" error.
*/
export default function mapToRange(counter, maxValue) {
  if (maxValue === undefined || maxValue === 0) return 0;
  // positive counter
  if (counter >= 0) return counter % maxValue;
  // negative counter
  const modulo = counter % maxValue;
  if (modulo === 0) {
      return modulo;
  }
  return modulo + maxValue;
}
```

I use this function to map the `counter`, a int number to the range between 0 and `maxValue`.

```
let counter = 0;
const array = ['apple', 'pear','peach'];
if(press arrow up) counter--;
else if (press arrow down) counter++;

let idx = mapInRange(counter, array.length)
console.log(array[idx]);
```

Imagine you have a drop down list and you want to navigate through the list with arrow keys.