# PUG playing with index

Tags: iteration, pug, slideshow

After using SO and found a lot of answers to feed my learning process, it's time for me (and because I haven't found any answer to my problem yet) to ask for your help.
I'm learning PUG since some days, and I'm trying to use "each" iteration to create a html/css slideshow (following the project of (shit, can't find the git anymore, too much projects based on this)).
Sorry.
Here's the pug code I made:

```
.slideshow
  each val, index in ['img-1.jpg', 'img-2.jpg', 'img-3.jpg']
    input(type="radio" name="ss" id='ss-img-' + index).ss-bullet
    .ss-img
      img(src=val)
      label(for='ss-img-' + *index*).ss-nav-prev Image précédente
      label(for='ss-img-' + *index*).ss-nav-next Image suivante
```

(.classes are just for later styling of the buttons/bullets)

And this is what I'm trying to obtain, in html:

```
<div class="slideshow">
      <input class="ss-bullet" type="radio" name="ss" id="ss-img-0">
      <div class="ss-img"><img src="img/img-1.jpg">
        <label class="ss-nav-prev" for="ss-img-2">Image précédente</label>
        <label class="ss-nav-next" for="ss-img-1">Image suivante</label>
      </div>
      <input class="ss-bullet" type="radio" name="ss" id="ss-img-1">
      <div class="ss-img"><img src="img/img-2.jpg">
        <label class="ss-nav-prev" for="ss-img-0">Image précédente</label>
        <label class="ss-nav-next" for="ss-img-2">Image suivante</label>
      </div>
      <input class="ss-bullet" type="radio" name="ss" id="ss-img-2">
      <div class="ss-img"><img src="img/img-3.jpg">
        <label class="ss-nav-prev" for="ss-img-1">Image précédente</label>
        <label class="ss-nav-next" for="ss-img-0">Image suivante</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Of course as you all noticed, the missing part is in the *index*:

```
label(for='ss-img-' + *index*)
```

part.

Can someone please teach me how to iterate the index to complete this?
(another thing you probably noticed is that i'm still new to javascript, and french)
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'iterate the index'? Isn't removing the asterisks in this case sufficient?

Comment: Hoy @gandreadis, Yes the *asterix* are just polluting the code... if removed, "index" just return the number of items in the sequence. What I'm trying to do is to return the previous and next item index. So for the first, something like: 'index--' and the second 'index++'. I've tried that with no success.

Comment: Ahhh, now I get it. See my answer for a possible solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you need is a simple bit of circular (wrap-around) arithmetic (see also answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325750/using-mod-to-wrap-around)):

```
- var arrayLength = 3;
label(for='ss-img-' + ((index + arrayLength - 1) % arrayLength)).ss-nav-prev Image précédente
label(for='ss-img-' + ((index + 1) % arrayLength)).ss-nav-next Image suivante
```

Comment: Thank you, this is already bringing me closer to my needs. By the way, when I add your code, the first and last elements are returning strange values (respectively: 8 that don't exist, and 3 that is over the max number for index). [link](http://jsbin.com/eqenag/1/edit) Looking at the interresting code from @Roko C. Buljan found in the link you gave me. That will be my day course.

Answer (score 0):

So with your code added:

```
.slideshow
  each val, index in ['img-1.jpg', 'img-2.jpg', 'img-3.jpg']
    input(type="radio" name="ss" id='ss-img-' + index)
    .ss-img
      img(src=val)
      label(for='ss-img-' + ((index + val.length - 1) % val.length)) Image précédente
      label(for='ss-img-' + ((index + 1) % val.length)) Image suivante
```

I'm getting this:

```
<div class="slideshow">
      <input type="radio" name="ss" id="ss-img-0">
      <div class="ss-img"><img src="img-1.jpg">
        <label for="ss-img-8">Image précédente</label>
        <label for="ss-img-1">Image suivante</label>
      </div>
      <input type="radio" name="ss" id="ss-img-1">
      <div class="ss-img"><img src="img-2.jpg">
        <label for="ss-img-0">Image précédente</label>
        <label for="ss-img-2">Image suivante</label>
      </div>
      <input type="radio" name="ss" id="ss-img-2">
      <div class="ss-img"><img src="img-3.jpg">
        <label for="ss-img-1">Image précédente</label>
        <label for="ss-img-3">Image suivante</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

(removed the classes to make it more clear)
As you can see, the first and last items are not yet looping as expected. Only the middle one is right.
(And sorry to use 'answer' instead of 'comment', I haven't found a way to write multiples lines code...)
Thanks again for helping!

Comment: But, you didn't actually include my code fully: The first line of my snippet is important! Right now, you're just measuring the length of each file-name string

Comment: Wat één newbie am I... Thanks you, with the variable added, it's working great. Now I just need to make `arrayLength` equals to the number of items in the string (and not the file-name string length, of course...) instead of having to define it with a number. Any idea?

Comment: You can define that array of images earlier in the code, through an embedded JS snippet (`- var images = [...]`), and iterate over that instead (`each val, index in images`). Then, instead of `arrayLength`, use `images.length` when retrieving array length.

Comment: Thank you so much ! You saved my day !

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: How, I need a last thing to finish completely this code. I need to seek for the first input (when the index is 0), and add the value `checked="checked"` to it. Tried with something like: `if index == 0; - var checked = 'checked="checked"'` but obviously it's not working... Any idea?

Comment: How about embedding that check in the attribute value? `checked=(index === 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final pug code for the one who wants to use it:

```
.slideshow
  - var imgs = ['img/img-1.jpg', 'img/img-2.jpg', 'img/img-3.jpg', 'img/img-4.jpg', 'img/img-5.jpg', 'img/img-6.jpg']
  each img, index in imgs
    input(type="radio" name="ss" id=('ss-img-' + index) checked=(index === 0)).ss-bullet
    .ss-img
      img(src=img)
      label(for='ss-img-' + ((index + imgs.length - 1) % imgs.length)).ss-nav-prev Image précédente
      label(for='ss-img-' + ((index + 1) % imgs.length)).ss-nav-next Image suivante
```