# creating multiple subnets per availability zone using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc

I am new to terraform. I want to create single public subnet and three private subnet per availability zone in particular region in AWS using terraform. I am able to create one private and public subnet per availability zone by referring the following link https://medium.com/@maneetkum/create-subnet-per-availability-zone-in-aws-through-terraform-ea81d1ec1883. However I need to split the one private subet created into another 2. Is that possible in terraform?

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}resource "aws_vpc" "myVpc" {
  cidr_block           = "10.20.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags {
    Name = "myVpc"
  }
}
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.myVpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.20.${10+count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags {
    Name = "PublicSubnet"
  }
}
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.myVpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.20.${20+count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone= "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags {
    Name = "PrivateSubnet"
  }
}
```

The above code is used to create the one private and public subnet per availability zone.

Comment: Why not duplicate the `private_subnet` resource element and change the CIDR blocks to create the additional 2 subnets?

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion...if it works...can you give the code format since I am new to terraform I am not aware of codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply duplicate the `private_subnet` resource element to create the two new subnets in each AZ:

```
...
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.myVpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.20.${20+count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone= "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags {
    Name = "PrivateSubnet"
  }
}
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_2" {
  count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)}"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.myVpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.30.${20+count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone= "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
  tags {
    Name = "PrivateSubnet2"
  }
}
```

You will need to modify the CIDR blocks for each subnet to make sure they don't overlap with each other.

Comment: Thanyou..thanx a let me work with the code and update on this

Comment: yes I am able to login but with little modification in Ip like 10.20.${20+count.index}.0/24" , 10.20${30+count.index}.0/24" and so on

Comment: OK great. Could you mark the answer as correct if it has answered the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to create multiple subnets, and automatically place them into an Availability Zone, without duplicating code.  Let's keep things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  To avoid duplicating the code, use the magic of Terraform meta-arguments and built-in functions.  Specifically, use "*[count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html)*" and "*[cidrsubnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrsubnet.html)*".  The "*[count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html)*", will generate as many copies of your subnet as you want.

If you want to provide each subnet with unique values, such as the subnet's tag  *Name*, you can give each subnet a unique, and mnemonic name, by creating a data dictionary with the names that you want assigned to each of the subnets. Then assign them as you create the subnets, by using "*[count.index](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html#count-index)*".   IF that is too much work, you could also just embed the *[count.index](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html#count-index)* in the name as well.

Different regions have a different number of Availability Zones.  To make sure that you are assigning your subnets to Availability Zones that actually exit, you should generate the [list of the Availability Zones](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zones) dynamically.  This way, you know that all of the Availability Zones, that are in the list, are actually available in the region that you are working.

What happens if you have more subnets then the region has Availability Zones?  Use [modulo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325750/ddg#14325845) arithmetic to wrap your working index.  Rather than using the [index.count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html#count-index) directly, do a [modulo](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/operators.html#a-b-4) on the [index.count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/count.html#count-index), using the [length](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/length.html) of the list. This will wrap the index around, so your working index never overflows the length of the list of Availability Zones.

But, the real magic is "*[cidrsubnet](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrsubnet.html)*" command.  The example below will take the size of the base CIDR block that is passed (which happens to be a /16), add the 2nd parameter (4), and generate a /20 CIDR block.  The third parameter indexes through the available CIDR block, thus ensuring that each subnet gets a different sub-CIDR block.

**Note**: The related [cidrsubnets](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/cidrsubnets.html) command is quite a bit different. So, be careful, and don't get the two functions confused.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "area_subnets" {
  count                   = 4 # creates four subnets
  vpc_id                  = var.area_vpc_id
  map_public_ip_on_launch = var.map_public_ip_on_launch

  cidr_block           = cidrsubnet(var.area_subnet_cidr, 4, count.index)
  availability_zone_id = data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids[count.index % length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.zone_ids)]

  tags = tomap({ "Name" = "${var.subnet_names[count.index]}" })
}

variable "subnet_names" {
  type = list(string)
  default = [
    "Primary NAT Gateway Subnet",
    "Secondary NAT Gateway Subnet",
    "Channel A Subnet",
    "Channel B Subnet"
  ]
}

variable "map_public_ip_on_launch" {
  type    = bool
  default = true
}

variable "area_vpc_id"
    documentation = "The Terraform ID of the containing VPC"
    type = string
    default = "vpc-abcdefghijklmno"
}

variable "area_subnet_cidr"
    documentation = "The base CIDR that you are working with"
    type = string
    default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {
  state = "available"

  filter { # Only fetch Availability Zones (no Local Zones)
    name   = "opt-in-status"
    values = ["opt-in-not-required"]
  }
}
```